# C++ Instantiating new object leads to same "this" pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I've been working with C++ recently and am quite new, so I might be missing something simple.

I have essentially the following code:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    struct MyStruct *parent;
    MyStruct();
}
MyStruct::MyStruct()
{
    parent = this;
}
```

And later in my `main` function, I have a `for` loop as follows:

```
std::vector<MyStruct> Collection;
Collection.reserve(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    Collection.push_back(MyStruct());
}
```

When I run my program, I expect to get a vector of `MyStruct` elements, each with a unique `parent` pointer. Instead, I get a vector where each element has the `parent` point initialized to the *same* memory address.

Why is the `parent` pointer the same for all of my objects? When I open `gdb` and type

```
(gdb) print Collection[0].parent
$1 = (Point *) 0x7fffffffdcd0
(gdb) print &Collection[0]
$2 = (Point *) 0x60b010
```

I would expect $1 and $2 to have the same value. Why don't they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a [copy constructor](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm). In your case, you are instantiating a stack-based instance of your object, and it's getting essentially `memcpy`d into your `vector`. Probably the stack instance is always at the same address, hence why you have the same `parent` pointer value.

<s>Another issue is that, if/when the `vector` needs to do a reallocation to make a larger internal array, all your `parent` values will of course not get automatically updated to a new (and correct) value. To avoid this, you need to call `reserve` on your `vector` ahead of time to whatever value makes sense for your case so that the array never gets reallocated.</s>

Nevermind; the copy constructor takes care of that issue as well.

Comment: As a side note, using `emplace_back` will work as expected.

Comment: @vsofco I tried `emplace_back` and it yielded the same result.

Comment: @vsoftco For some odd definition of "expected". The address might be different in each element (if you do `emplace_back()`), but with reallocation, it's unlikely that `Collection[0].parent == &Collection[0]` .

Comment: True, to avoid that issue, you would need to call `reserve` ahead of time to avoid the reallocation issue with this particular `struct`. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @T.C. you're right, reallocation messes everything up.

Comment: By the way, thanks for mentioning `emplace_back`. I'm an old fart, so I am still using compilers that aren't necessarily C++11 compliant, so I hadn't even heard of that new member function. It's awesome, and I wish it existed long ago so that I could have avoided all sorts of workarounds when dealing with `vector` in performant-sensitive code.

Comment: @JimBuck Thanks for the answer. As to the second part, what implementation would avoid having to `reserve` everything ahead of time? There is one vector that this is trivial to do this for, but for another vector I can't.

Comment: @JimBuck Quite weird, re-allocation doesn't seem to mess things up when having the proper copy constructor. i.e., it seems that `&Colection[i] == Colection[i].parent` is always true.

Comment: @vsoftco Right, if you have a correct copy ctor that fix up the self reference, then reallocation won't do anything wrong - but then the code in the OP with `push_back` would also work.

Comment: @T.C. still don't get it why exactly. My copy ctor looks like `MyStruct(const MyStruct& rhs): parent(this){}`. When the vector reallocates, doesn't it first allocates via placement new, then constructs in place? Why would then `Collection[i].parent == &Collection[i]`?

Comment: @vsoftco - are you sure it's reallocating then? It would absolutely mess up the `parent` pointers for earlier array elements than the one you just `push_back`d. @T.C. A correct copy ctor would only be ok for the element currently being `push_back`d. If/when a reallocation occurs during a `push_back`, all previous elements in the array will have incorrect `parent` pointers.

Comment: @tanderson11 - you have no way of calculating some (reasonable) upper bound on the number of elements even if many of those elements may not eventually get used?

Comment: @JimBuck I'm pretty sure, I push_back in a loop up to 1024 elements.

Comment: @vsoftco - Yeah, but if your `vector` already pre-allocated that many to begin with, you wouldn't trigger a reallocation. I would place a breakpoint at the reallocation line of code just to be sure.

Comment: @JimBuck no, it's not pre-allocated, I removed the `reserve` line

Comment: @vsoftco - Depending on your platform's implementation, there is still some amount pre-reserved. It's kind of like how `string` works.

Comment: @vsoftco - Heck, just as a test, just print the address of the first element after every `push_back` to see if/when it changes. In any case, it's easy to see how the `parent` pointer would get invalidated *if* reallocation happens *and* that reallocation changes the internal `vector`'s base pointer (perhaps your reallocation is getting lucky and keeping the same base pointer, but that's of course not a guarantee).

Comment: @vsoftco Because reallocation copies (well, moves-if-noexcept, but your copy ctor suppresses the move ctor) the existing elements, so they all got fixed up too by your copy constructor.

Comment: Ahh, good point! The copy ctor rescues this realloc situation as well. Duh on me.

Comment: @T.C. Ohh yes of course, damn, that's absolutely right. Missed it that when copying, the target invokes the copy ctor, which initializes the parent with the "right" `this`.

Comment: @JimBuck In my implementation, each copy of MyStruct also has a vector associated with it. Since implementing the copy constructor, that vector has been getting enormous. Is there something I should change in my copy constructor?

Comment: @tanderson11 - What is your copy constructor doing?

Comment: @JimBuck. I got it to work. I stupidly did not copy the vector so I assume something wacky was going on. Thanks.

Comment: @tanderson11 - Ohh, ok, that would do it. :)